# Using filter() and Arguments object. Logical Error?

Tags: javascript

Aim of Script: An array and multiple arguments are passed into a function. An array must be returned, minus the elements that are the same as the arguments.

There are no Syntax errors and I can't seem to figure out the fault in my logic.

```
function destroyer(arr) {

 function isTheDestroyer(x) {

   //Using the arguments object
   for (i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
      if (x == arguments[i]) {
         return false;
        }
   }
   return true;
 }

var filtered = arguments[0].filter(isTheDestroyer);
return filtered;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

The output is unchanged when I run it.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what `arguments` is within `isTheDestroyer`?  I strongly suspect it's not what you think it is.

Comment: @James Thorpe Oh I see, then how do I access the 'arguments' in 'isTheDestroyer' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @James Thorpe. arguments in isTheDestroyer is not the same that arguments in destroyer (in reality it's not in same order). I recommend to you to use a closure

```
function destroyer(arr) {

var args = arguments;
function isTheDestroyer(x) {

  //Using the arguments object
  for (i=1; i<args .length; i++) {
    if (x == args [i]) {
      return false;
     }
   }
  return true;
}

var filtered = arguments[0].filter(isTheDestroyer);
return filtered;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! i should have figured out that all functions would have their own 'arguments' object.